# Find which axis getting copied during broadcast

Tags: numpy, array-broadcasting

I am looking for an elegant way to find which axis getting “copied” during a [broadcast](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).
Here is what I came up with:

```
# broadcast a matrix of shape "shape" into one with shape "broadcast_to". 
shape = (3, 1, 1)
broadcast_to =  (4, 3, 1, 6)

# left pad with 1 
extended_shape = (1,) * (len(broadcast_to) - len(shape)) + tuple(shape)

# axis [0, 3] will be copied during broadcast
axis = [ax for ax in range(len(broadcast_to)) if broadcast_to[ax] != extended_shape[ax]]
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I think in terms of 2 "rules". 1) add leading dimension(s) as needed to match the total number.  2) 'adjust" all size 1 dimensions.  '2' is possible without copy or repeat because the stride value is 0.